# Variable as a length in RIGHT SQL function?

Tags: abap, opensql

I want to use this Open SQL code in my ABAP code :

```
  SELECT RIGHT( NODENAME, LENGTH( NODENAME ) - 8 )
      FROM  RSMHIERNODE
      WHERE HIEID = 'HRJ'
      INTO TABLE @lt_commentdata.
```

but when I try to activate the method I have this error :

> In the function RIGHT , the parameter number 2 must be an abap variable. this is not the case for the expression that starts with 'LENGTH'.

Have any idea how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use operator for length of RIGHT function. You need to give exact value. You can use SUBSTRING function with huge length.
Example:

```
SUBSTRING( NODENAME, 8, 999 )
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING(NODENAME, 8, 999)` produces a syntax error because of missing spaces around parentheses. Shouldn't it be 9 instead of 8? Note that the parameter 2 of `RIGHT` can be a SQL expression from ABAP 7.55.

Comment: thank you mkysoft , it solves the problem . Just as @SandraRossi said there is a missing spaces around parentheses .