# Substring length as variable in OpenSQL query?

Tags: abap, opensql

I want to select the length of the string ( LGOBE ) minus 4.

But i get this error:
"In the function "SUBSTRING", the parameter number "3" must be an ABAP variable.
This is not the case for the expression that starts with       "LENGTH"."

What I understand from this message is that i cannot use a function as the third parameter, is this interpretation correct?
If so, is there an alternative for me to remove the last 4 places of the string inside the select statement? Thank you.

```
  SELECT
  SUBSTRING( LGOBE,1, LENGTH( LGOBE ) - 4 ) AS TEST1,
  LGOBE, WERKS
  FROM T001L INTO TABLE @DATA(IT_FINAL)
  UP TO 100 ROWS.

  CL_DEMO_OUTPUT=>DISPLAY( IT_FINAL ).
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable as a length in RIGHT SQL function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69257025/variable-as-a-length-in-right-sql-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the [754](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_754_index_htm/7.54/en-US/index.htm?file=abensql_string_func.htm) documentation:

> SUBSTRING( sql_exp,pos,len )  sql_exp: see below
>
> pos: Literal, host variable, or host expression with the ABAP type b, s, i, int8
>
> len: **Literal or host constant with the ABAP type b, s, i, int8**

Now [755](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_755_index_htm/7.55/en-US/index.htm?file=abensql_string_func.htm):

> SUBSTRING( sql_exp,pos,len )
>
> Substring sql_exp from the position pos with length len. pos and len must be specified so that the substring is within sql_exp.   sql_exp: see below
>
> pos: SQL expression with the ABAP type b, s, i, int8
>
> len: **SQL expression** with the ABAP type b, s, i, int8

Interestingly I cannot find that mentioned in the release notes itself.
So either you upgrade to 755 release or you'll have to do the processing in ABAP after selection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have reputation enough to upvote but thanks.